# Error in implementing "transpose" layer in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to implement the transpose function in Caffe using a Python layer. 
Below is the code for the same.

However, it is throwing the error "terminate called after throwing an instance of `boost::python::error_already_set` at `Reshape()` method.

Can someone throw some light on what I am doing wrong?

```
import caffe
import numpy as np

class transpose(caffe.Layer):

    def setup(self, bottom, top):
        assert len(bottom) == 1,            'requires a single layer.bottom'
        assert bottom[0].data.ndim == 2,    'requires matrix data'
        assert len(top) == 1,               'requires a single layer.top'

    def reshape(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].reshape((bottom[0].data.shape[1], bottom[0].data.shape[0]))

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].data = np.transpose(bottom[0].data)

    def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
        pass
```

Thank you, 
Vijetha.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3594) is a discussion regarding permute layer. It may be relevant. The code for that layer is available [here](https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/permute_layer.cpp) or [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/b68695db42aa79e874296071927536363fe1efbf/src/caffe/layers/permute_layer.cpp).

Comment: what about a backward pass, transposing the gradients as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are `reshape`ing incorrectly.
Try:

```
def reshape(self, bottom, top):
  top[0].reshape(bottom[0].data.shape[1], bottom[0].data.shape[0])
```

`shape` arguments for `Reshape` are *not* given as a tupple but rather as a separate arguments.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Also, is the backward method correct? I am not very sure about this method too. Like you commented, should I transpose the previous gradient that is passed from top?

Comment: @VijethaGattupalli you need to set bottom[0].diff using top.[0].diff. you'll need to transpose...

Comment: So it would be bottom[0].diff = np.transpose(top[0].diff). I believe 'pass' only would make bottom[0].diff = top[0].diff. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VijethaGattupalli pass means pass. it means I have no idea what is going to be in bottom[0].diff... Why should caffe assign top[0].diff to bottom[0].diff?

Comment: I was guessing 'pass' in reshape method would just replicate the shape of bottom layer to the top, so a similar thing could be happening in backward method. But thank you for your clarification. I understood how to write it now.